# Has the reaserch on the back cover of journal been benefitial for you or your group?

Tags: publications, reference-request, publishers

> You can highlight your article and the work of your group on the back cover of ----Name of journal from RCS-----, if you are interested in this opportunity please contact me for more information

Have you ever got this offer from above mention publisher ( or in general ) and can it be beneficial for visibility of your research? Is there any scientific evidence ( publication ) that backcover brings more readers and attention to your work? or this is just atempt of publishers to capitalise on scientist ego?

Comment: Is that Royal Society? Are you required to pay them for this?

Comment: @MajidAbdolshah Yes. No.

Answer (score 3):

Well I believe no one can prove the answer is strictly yes or no. It depends on the Journal, the topic we are working on and the amount of people who are getting these copies (and who are these people). But I believe in some fields (e.g. industrial applications) it may attract attention.

> Is there any scientific evidence ( publication ) that back cover brings more readers and attention to your work?

Yes there are studies on this topic. Check this one (Though, it proves the opposite): [Does A Paper Being Featured on The Cover of A Journal Guarantee More Attention and Greater Impact?](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1410/1410.3705.pdf)

On the other hand [Wiley](https://authorservices.wiley.com/author-resources/Journal-Authors/Promotion/journal-cover-image.html) believes:

> One of the best ways to showcase your work is with an eye-catching journal issue cover. After your article is accepted for publication, you can submit your idea for a cover image. Your suggestion may be featured in your article’s journal issue.

All in all, why not to try it once and see the results!

Comment: yes, is there any paper about back page?